# Data not getting passed via Ajax to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying to send the value of a variable *number* via ajax to a PHP script. But the PHP script is not printing the desired output on opening on a browser. Tried but couldn't find whats wrong here. 
Any pointers ?

**index.html**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id = 'first' onclick='process();'>Submit</button>

<script>

var number = 0;

function process()
{
    number++;

    var xhr;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    var data = "num=" + number;
    xhr.open("POST", "index.php", true);
    xhr.send(data);
}     
</script>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$number = $_POST['num'];
$_SESSION['numb'] = $number;
echo $_SESSION['numb'] ;
?>
```

Comment: How are you checking the output? If you open the same PHP again with a plain GET request, you will overwrite the old number.

Comment: Check your Javascript console for errors. You're missing the close brace for the function, so it's not running.

Comment: Well yea, you're not using `isset()` on the `$_POST` so the `$_SESSION` is being set to `false` and the echo is blank on direct page reuqest.

Comment: You're JS has syntax errors, you're using a submit button so you'll reload the page if it is in a form, and you aren't doing anything with the HTTP response that is sent to your JS!

Comment: The output of the index.php (echo) is sent back to the XHR object in index.html. I don't see where you retrieve that response.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Added the content type of the request in index.html and used isset() on the $_POST on index.php. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing my long winded lame answer since you fixed the close curly bracket... but bloodyKnuckles is right you also need something in your 'process' function to take the response from your PHP page and output it... or whatever you want to do.  You can basically use the method 'onreadystatechange' in the XMLHttpRequest object and then look for a 'readyState' property value of 4 which means everything is done.  Here is a simple example of that just outputting the results to the console (which you can view using developer tools in your browser of choice).

```
<script>

var number = 0;

function process()
{
number++;

var xhr;

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

var data = "num=" + number;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){            

  if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
          console.log('xhr.readyState=',xhr.readyState);
          console.log('xhr.status=',xhr.status);
          console.log('response=',xhr.responseText);               
  }

  else if (xhr.readyState == 1 ){
    xhr.send(data)

  }

};

xhr.open("POST", "ajax-test.php", true);

}
</script>
```

As you go further you may want to update your PHP page to only update the session when the POST value is there.

```
<?php
//ini_set('display_errors',1);
//ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
//error_reporting(-1);
if(isset($_POST['num'])){
            session_start();
    $_SESSION['numb'] = $_POST['num'];
    echo $_SESSION['numb'];
}
?>
```

You can uncomment those ini_set and error_reporting lines to try to figure out what is going on with your PHP script.

Comment: he added the close brace when he edited the question several minutes ago.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did output it on the cconsole. Added the content type of the request in index.html and used isset() on the $_POST on index.php. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not sending header information with request...

Append this code

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

after

```
xhr.open("POST", "index.php", true);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Added the content type of the request in index.html and used isset() on the $_POST on index.php. It works now.